# Что означает знак вопроса в C#?

Tags: c#

Что означает знак вопроса в C#? Например здесь

```
get
{
    return name != null ? name : "NA";
}
```

и можно ли его еще где использовать?

Comment: ну это же тернарный оператор :'(

Comment: Спасибо за название, а то я даже не знал как его гуглить...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а не подскажите, зачем используют резервное хранилище?  `class Person
{
    private string name;  // the name field
    public string Name    // the Name property
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @Denisok захотелось так потому что. Только это называется совсем не так.

Comment: _Тернарным_ называется любой оператор с _тремя_ операндами. Оператор, о котором идёт речь, называется «условный оператор».

Comment: гуглить так "c# operator msdn". Для ленивых тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6a71f45d.aspx Читайте внимательно, значение некоторых символов в C# зависит от контекста,  `?` в их числе

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Условный оператор `(?:)` (он же ***тернарный оператор***) возвращает одно из двух значений в зависимости от значения логического выражения. Для условного оператора используется следующий синтаксис

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Параметр `condition` должен иметь значение **true** или **false**. Если параметр `condition` имеет значение **true**, вычисляется выражение *first_expression* и итог этого вычисления становится результатом.

Если параметр `condition` имеет значение **false**, вычисляется выражение *second_expression* и итог этого вычисления становится результатом.

В любом случае вычисляется только одно из двух выражений.
Параметры *first_expression* и *second_expression* должны быть одинакового типа или должно существовать неявное преобразование из одного типа в другой.

Расчеты, которые в другом случае требовали бы уточнения конструкции **if-else**, можно выражать с помощью условного оператора. Например, в следующем коде сначала используется оператор **if**, а затем — условный оператор для того, чтоб уведомить было ли введенное пользователем число - числом пять или нет:

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// Обычная конструкция if-else.
if (input == 5)
    classify = "Вы ввели число 5! Молодец!";
else
    classify = "Это НЕ число 5! Это бяка!";


// ?: оператор.
classify = (input == 5) ? "Вы ввели число 5! Молодец!" : "Это НЕ число 5! Это бяка!";
```

**[_Источник_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty67wk28.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

```
if(name != null)
   return name;
else
   return "NA";
```

`?` означает если

`:` означает иначе

Comment: Спасибо вам...)