# Чем отличаются условный оператор от тернарного?

Tags: любой-язык, терминология, тернарный-оператор

Изучала тему знака вопроса в языках. Нашла такой вопрос на стаке: [Что означает знак вопроса в C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543129/440444)

В комменатариях к этому вопросу были сообщения:

> - ну это же тернарный оператор :'( – Алексей Шиманский 9 июл '16 в 14:25
>
> - *Тернарным* называется любой оператор с *тремя* операндами. Оператор, о котором идёт речь, называется «условный оператор». – VladD 9 июл '16 в 17:58

И я запуталась. Везде в интернете подобная конструкция называется тернарником

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary
- и т.д.

Объясните пожалуйста, почему указанный в самом начале оператор - условный, а не тернарный? Каково опредедление условного оператора? И тогда в чём его отличие от тернарного? И каково реальное определение тернарного и как он тогда выглядит?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F. Операции бывают унарные, бинарные и тернарные в зависимости от количества операндов. Сокращённо принято тернарную условную операцию называть просто тернарной операцией.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это тернарный условный оператор. Не надо противопоставлять - у данного оператора два свойства - он и условный, и тернарный.

По функциональности оператор `?`  условный (как `if, switch`)

По количеству операндов - тернарный (бывают ещё бинарные и унарные)

---

Ваше предположение `оператор - условный, а не тернарный` не имеет под собой оснований. VladD не утверждал, что оператор не является тернарным, он только уточнил, что это не единственная его характеристика (т.е. могут существовать и другие тернарные операторы).

Если на пальцах - есть несколько видов овощей, один из них - баклажан - синий. Он и овощ (главное свойство) и синий (вторичное). Синие плоды редки, поэтому иногда можно сказать "синенький" - и будет понятно.

Comment: Мне всё равно не ясно. Тернарный оператор получается является в том числе условным? Почему тогда  VladD  написал, что оператор, о котором идёт речь, называется «условный оператор», а не тернарный?

Comment: `Тернарный оператор получается является в том числе условным?` Да. Только скорее наоборот - функциональность важнее - **один из условных операторов, а именно `?`, является тернарным**.  VladD вовсе не писал, что он **не** является тернарным.

Comment: @Иришка, конкретно оператор `?:` в языках C#, C, C++ и других является **условным**, потому что, грубо говоря, «выбирает одно из двух» в зависимости от *условия*. Кроме того, так как у этого оператора `?:` три операнда, то он еще называется **тернарным**, как и любой другой оператор с тремя операндами. Не стоит так сильно заморачиваться, вас все поймут, если назовете его просто тернарным.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понятно. @eanmos тоже помог всё более чётко понять (Его комментарий можно даже как дополнение в ответ добавить).

Answer (score 2):

Тернарный оператор так назвали потому, что он работает с тремя операндами. Тернарный оператор условный, так как выполнение программы/значение переменной/значение возврата зависит от условия как и у if/switch даже while/for. Условных операторов несколько. Тернарный не исключение, так как он базируется на логическом выражении. Условный оператор - некая абстракция.

Оператор `?:` предоставляет сокращенный способ (альтернативу) ветвления `if/else`. Его стоит использовать когда от условия зависит значение переменной. Например `int x = (var > 2) ? 1 : 0` . Проверяем, `var` больше чем 2? Тогда присваиваем переменной значение после знака вопроса(1) иначе - 0. Еще пример - `return (guessed == ok) ? true : false;` Но не стоит ним употреблять так как он может сделать код не понятным.

Например, с помощю тернарного оператора можно присвоить значение переменной с атрибутом `const`, что не сделаешь через обычный `if/else`.

Comment: Мне всё ещё не совсем ясно. Тернарный оператор получается является в том числе условным? Почему тогда VladD написал, что оператор, о котором идёт речь, называется «условный оператор», а не тернарный?

Comment: и правильно он сказал

Comment: Потому что там фигурирует условие=)

Comment: Тернарный оператор условный, так как выполнение программы зависит от условия как и у if/switch даже while/for

Comment: Условный оператор - некая абстракция. Условные операторы бывают в виде if/switch/?:

Comment: Поняли?........

Comment: *`"с помощю тернарного оператора можно присвоить значение константе"`* -- наверное вы имели в виду объявление переменной с атрибутом `const`, а не настоящую константу?

Comment: Именно! Я вас благодарю