# Не пойму что за знак "?" после типа переменной. Его предназначение и свойства

Tags: c#

Открыл для себя вот такую новую синтаксическую "конструкцию". Не могу найти ответ в гугле. Подскажите как это правильно называется и какие функции у этой "штуки". Как я догадался логически, одна из фишек это метод HasValue, что тоже кажется странным для меня, ибо почему не использовать value == null ? 1 : 0;
Понимаю, что скорее всего вопрос глупый, но я только осваиваю язык, поэтому вот...)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: этот знак это сокращённая записть `Nullable<T>`

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543129/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не, это не про тот знак вопроса спрашивается))

Comment: Код в вопрос рекомендуется вставлять текстом.

Answer (score 2):

`?` оператор используется в коде следующим образом:

1. `SomeType? myVariable`, данная запись эквивалентна `Nullable<SmthType> myVariable`, где `SmthType` - `struct`.
   В C# 8.0 были добавлены nullable reference types, позволяющие делать `nullable` еще и классы.
2. `?` используется при вызове методов у классов. Это проверка на `null`. В данном случае, если объект класса `myClassObject` имеет значение `null` - то, метод не будет вызван.

```
myClassObject?.SmthMethod();
```

Тоже самое, что и:

```
if(myClassObject != null)
{
   myClassObject.SmthMethod();
}
```

3. Для условных конструкций:

```
int a = 0;
if(boolVariable == true)
{
   a++
}
else 
{
   a--;
}
```

Почти тоже самое, только результат нужно записывать в какую-нибудь переменную

```
int a = 0;
int c = boolVariable == true ? a++ : a--; //c - результат выражения a++ или a--
```

Comment: Отвыйкайте от `== true`. :)

Comment: @aepot, знаю, но у меня мания какая-то на ```== true```. Ощущение, что этот код сработает иначе, если не напишу именно так